# W3Schools Slides same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I added text to a modified slideshow from w3schools. My problem now is, that the text divs are not equally in height. I want the text divs be as big as the biggest text div of the 3 slides and I don't want to set a specific height to the text div, because that will make the responsiveness hard to manage (meaning a lot of work with media queries and even with that not 100% perfect). I looked through many posts here about the same topic, but i couldn't come up with a solution for me. Code is below or [here](https://jsfiddle.net/32k9ynax/). Appreciate any help.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant&display=swap');
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/yoj6eqg.css");

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 92%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  }
  
  /* text color */
.text {
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Assistant", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 1vh 0 0 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #90bd49;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "p22-underground", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  padding: 1.5vh 0 0 0;
}

/* Prev Button Position and Properties */
.prev {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Next Button Position and Properties */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  right: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}
.image
{
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 60vh;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}
.active {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(22px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(14px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 3vw 0 3vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
  .image {
    height: 350px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(20px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(12px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 2vw 0 2vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(18px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 2.5vw 0 2.5vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1301px) and (max-width:1650px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(18px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.390625vw);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1651px){
.heading {
  font-size: calc(16px + 0.390625vw);
}
.text {
  font-size: calc(8px + 0.390625vw);
}

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dot-container">
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the `display` property, so you need to set the container to a height that is equal to the largest height of the slides.

```js
window.onload = setSliderHeight;
window.onresize = setSliderHeight;

function setSliderHeight() {
  let maxSlideHeight = 0;
  const container = document.querySelector('.slideshow-container');
  container.style.removeProperty('height');
  document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides').forEach(el => maxSlideHeight = el.offsetHeight > maxSlideHeight ? el.offsetHeight : maxSlideHeight);
  container.style.height = maxSlideHeight + 'px';
}

/* your code is below */

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant&display=swap');
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/yoj6eqg.css");

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 92%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* changed */
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /* text color */
.text {
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Assistant", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 1vh 0 0 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #90bd49;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "p22-underground", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  padding: 1.5vh 0 0 0;
}

/* Prev Button Position and Properties */
.prev {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Next Button Position and Properties */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  right: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}
.image
{
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 60vh;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}
.active {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(22px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(14px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 3vw 0 3vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
  .image {
    height: 350px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(20px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(12px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 2vw 0 2vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(18px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.390625vw);
    padding: 1vh 2.5vw 0 2.5vw;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1301px) and (max-width:1650px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: calc(18px + 0.390625vw);
  }

  .text {
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.390625vw);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1651px){
.heading {
  font-size: calc(16px + 0.390625vw);
}
.text {
  font-size: calc(8px + 0.390625vw);
}

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="heading">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dot-container">
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
```